# Max retries exceeded with URL Error on using requests.get()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to write a script in python to send HTTP get request to automatically generated URLs and get its response code and elapsed time. The URLs need not necessarily be a valid one, 400 responses are acceptable too.

#### script1.py

```
import sys
import requests

str1="http://www.googl"
str3=".com"
str2='a'

for x in range(0, 8):
    y = chr(ord(str2)+x)
    str_s=str1+y+str3
    r=requests.get(str_s)
    print(str_s, r.status_code, r.elapsed.total_seconds())
```

#### Error:

```
File "script1.py", line 12, in <module><br>
    r=requests.get(str_s)<br>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get<br>
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)<br>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request<br>
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)<br>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request<br>
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)<br>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send<br>
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)<br>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send<br>
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)<br>
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.googla.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc44c891e50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

- I just want see the time taken to receive response of each request.
- Only one request has to be sent
- Response code does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to get something like this:

```
import sys
import requests

str1="http://www.googl"
str3=".com"
str2='a'

for x in range(0, 8):
    y = chr(ord(str2)+x)
    str_s=str1+y+str3
    print('Connecting to ' + str_s)
    try:
        r = requests.get(str_s)
        print(str_s, r.status_code, r.elapsed.total_seconds())
    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        print("  Failed to open url")
```

In this case, using the `try...except` you can catch the exception that `get` raises and handle it in a nice way.

Comment: I want to see the Time taken to receive 400 Error codes too. Not just 200.

Comment: Make use of `time.time()`

Comment: The Desired output I'm looking for is response time for responses with 400 response_code. It works fine with 200 response_code but with 400 response code the connection does not close and the error message shown above pops up. I have tried connection:close in GET request , r.close() towards the end of loop.. but still no luck!!